# Understanding scanRight in Scala

Tags: scala, collections

I am having trouble understanding the following implementation of the `scanRight` function in Scala.

```
def scanRight[B](z: B)(f: (A, => B) => B): Stream[B] =
    foldRight((z, Stream(z)))((a, p0) => {
      lazy val p1 = p0
      val b2 = f(a, p1._1)
      (b2, cons(b2, p1._2))
    })._2
```

A typical application of scanRight would be

`Stream(1, 2, 3).scanRight(0)(_ + _).toList`

which produces the familiar `List(1+2+3, 1+2, 1, 0)`.

In particular, I do not understand what `p0` is here. It seems to be a tuple? But where is this tuple coming from?

Please note that this specific implementation is taken from [here](https://github.com/fpinscala/fpinscala/blob/master/answers/src/main/scala/fpinscala/laziness/Stream.scala)

Thx and please let me know should you need more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tuple is the argument to the `foldRight` call: `(z, Stream(z))`. The first value in the tuple is the result of the scan so far. The second value is the `Stream` that will be the eventual result of the `scanRight` call.

Each pass of the `fold` updates the result of the scan by calling `f` on the current value in the sequence (`a`) and the previous scan value (the first element in the tuple). The result is added to the stream (in the second element of the tuple) using `cons`. Both values are passed on to the next iteration of the `fold` as a new tuple.

When the `fold` finishes it returns the tuple, but only the second element is required by `scanRight` so is extracted from that tuple (`._2`) and returned.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for your help. `(z, Stream(z))` is the zero element to the `foldRight` call, correct? So, I though this would be applied in the end in a `foldRight`. Why do you say that it holds the "first value of the tuple"?

Comment: Further, I also believed that `foldRight` applies the function specified between the `{}` with the arguments being the head and the cons of the stream. But this does not seem to be the case here. Do you know what I am missing here?

Comment: The tuple is the *starting* element for the `foldRight` and is the value of `p0` the first time the block is called. But because `foldRight` scans the list backwards (from end to start) it is also the *last* element in the result. The block is called with a tuple where the first value is the current element in the list, and the second value is whatever was returned from the last call to the block.

Answer (score 0):

The question is already answered, but noticed that the result you posted is not the expected one (that would be a reversed result for a `foldLeft` operation.)

Given this function uses `foldRight`, the value to scan will be given from right to left, resulting this as outcome:
`List(1+2+3, 2+3, 3, 0)`

Final 0 is the initial value (0, Stream(0))

I hope I had explained well.